# How to add and access elements in nested vector pairs?

Tags: c++, stl

```
struct MyStruct1

{

int id1;

CString str1;

};

struct MyStruct2

{

int id1;

int id2;

CString str2;

};

struct MyStruct3

{

int id2;

int id3;

CString str3;

};

struct MyStruct4

{

int id3;

int id4;

CString str4;

};
```

I need to create nested vector of pairs as below.

```
vector<pair<
MyStruct1,
vector<pair<
MyStruct2,
vector<pair<
MyStruct3,
vector<MyStruct4>
>>
>>
>> m_vector;
```

I dont know how to do below operations on nested vector of pairs.

1. Adding elements
2. Accessing elements
3. How to extract anyone of the vector nested vector of pairs.
4. How to find elements?
5. How to update elements?
6. how to remove elements?
7. How to traverse the elements?

In internet I am finding examples only for  simple vector of pairs.
I am using not C++11.

Please anyone help me.

Comment: Show us what you've tried in order to achieve the same.

Comment: The answer to all of the questions, except 2, is find the element you `vector` want to operate on and operate exactly the same way you would with a single, un-nested `vector`. You've already found documentation on that. This leaves you with only question 2. But as it happens, when you know how to iterate through a single `vector`, you just nest whatever loop seems most appropriate.